# IKVM - NoSuchProviderException - no such provider: SunMSCAPI

Tags: c#, java, ikvm, mscapi

i new to using IKVM. I'm working on project in .NET, but some of its functionality is easier to do in Java. I need to use few java Jars (from WSS4J and Axis). I generate script.cmd file using jar2ikvmc. I run this file and get dlls from jars. But when i reference those dlls in my C# project and using them i get this NoSuchProviderException.

Here is stackTrace from Exception:

> v sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(String type, String algorithm, String provider)
>
> v sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(String type, Class clazz, String algorithm, >String provider)
>
> v java.security.Security.getImpl(String , String , String )
>
> v java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(String type, String provider)
>
> v cz.praktik.vzpmodul.b2b.B2BSluzby.nactiAlias(String )
>
> v cz.praktik.vzpmodul.b2b.B2BSluzby..ctor(String serioveCisloKlice)
>
> v VzpModulTest.Program.Main(String[] args) v C:\Users\florian\Documents\Visual Studio >2008\Projects\VzpModulTest\VzpModulTest\Program.cs:řádek 21
>
> v System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>
> v System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, >String[] args)
>
> v Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> v System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> v System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, >ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> v System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Any idea how to solve this problem? Project in Java works just fine for me. I have Windows7 32b.

Thank you.

Comment: Someone (it looks like `cz.praktik.vzpmodul.b2b.B2BSluzby.nactiAlias`) is trying to manually load a specific interface implementation instead of letting the system find a matching implementation, and the classes in the unofficial `sun` namespace aren't available to IKVM.

Comment: Yeah you're right, but there is only one way how to use MicroSoft CryptoAPI in Java that i know and it is through SunMSCAPI. I have to find some way how to use SunMSCAPI in IKVM. Do you have any idea?